# Angular 2: HTTP GET Request with ID

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have a http get request for a specific object. Therefore, I pass the ID in the request. On the serverside the value is now ${id} but not the actual passed number. What am I doing wrong? In another app it's working..

Service

```
getLeague(id){
    return this.http.get('api/leagues/${id}').map(res => res.json());
};
```

Server-side

```
router.route('/:league_id')
     .get(function(req,res){
         League.findOne({id: req.params.league_id})
     .exec(function(err,docs){
         if(err)
         res.send(err);
     res.json(docs);
  })});
```

In my test code I just simply call, e.g. getLeague(5), however, I receive the error (seems like ID ist not holding the actual value but just the variable name):

```
message: "Cast to number failed for value "${id}" at path "id" for model "League"", name: "CastError", stringValue: ""${id}"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using string interpolation ([Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)). Instead of single quotes, you need back ticks around your URL.

Answer (score 2):

You do not pass {{id}} to your link yet. Your request to backend includes "/${id}" part. To resolve variable in string in Typescript you should wrap your string with ticks to utilize interpolation, i.e.

```
return this.http.get(`api/leagues/${id}`).map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the syntax in this [URL](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings#syntax)

```
`api/leagues/${id}`
```

Using back tick **``**` should fix this